# How to change MAIN activity during runtime

Tags: android, program-entry-point, launcher

I have two activities (LoginActivity and MainActivity) with the LoginActivity being the MAIN and LAUNCHER in the android manifest file. Once the App launches, I don't want to go back to the LoginActivity even when Back button is pressed. How can I ensure the MainActivity becomes the main/ home activity though its not in the manifest as the MAIN during run time.

Comment: override the back button to implement the code what ever you want or put the `android:noHistory="true"` in activity tag or finish the activity once when you move to next activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `finish()` method of the `Activity` class on successfull log in.You will never see that `Activity` again in your application (obviously you must have to apply logic's to make it appear again, when some user logs out)

Do it like this
When user is authenticated by correct username-password combination

```
Intent i=new Intent(LogInActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Then the previous activity (`LogInActivity`) will be finished.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `finish()` of the `activity` class after starting new intent on `LoginActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.Class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // Call once you redirect to another activity
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding [android:noHistory="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory) to your `<activity>` tag in android manifest xml file